# How do OS X applications "clean" memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, memory-management

I would like to know how to "clean" memory on Mac OS X.  If you hav the developer tools installed, you can use the `purge` command to clean the memory.  However, if the dev tools are  *not* installed, this command will not work.  Other applications are able to do this so I know it's possible.

How might one program an app that would "clean" the memory, meaning remove inactive memory and make more space available in free memory?

Comment: Good question.  I've always wondered how these apps did it.  I guess they can't be using private APIs or they would be kicked from the Mac App Store.

Comment: They don't, really. They just eat as much memory as they can to force other apps to purge.

Comment: My friends told me this looks like it might be closed for "off topic".  This does relate to programming :/

Comment: @Yep I think if you edit the question and make it about the concept of "'cleaning memory' on OS X" or "'cleaning memory' in objective-C" it would be less likely to be closed again should it get reopened (and it would help your chances of it being reopened/answered

Comment: Ahh, edit wars.  Sorry for overriding someone's edit. :/

Comment: @Yep yours is better anyway, this is much better

Comment: Actually, the "off topic" close reason has been recently split; it used to cover questions like this.  The more appropriate close reason would be "Not Constructive", which means the question... **is not a good fit to our Q&A format.** We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or **extended discussion**....  IMHO, its borderline.

Comment: This question might have some relevant information for this: [clear buffer cache on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459537/clear-buffer-cache-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Found more info in a comment (by guns) on TUAW here: http://www.tuaw.com/2008/02/21/ifreemem-2-0-when-you-just-dont-feel-like-rebooting/2

Answer (score 5):

One workaround is to malloc as much memory as you can, then free that memory. See the code below taken from another example:

```
ints = size / sizeof(unsigned int);

unsigned int* mem;
mem = (unsigned int*) malloc(size);

for (i=0; i<ints; i++) {
    mem[i] = rand();
}

free(mem);
```

Of course it's up to you to decide what you mean by clearing memory, and how much to malloc.

Comment: About the Note at the bottom: -> What is the best way to decide how many to allocate ?